# How to use a function twice?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, csv, parameters

I have to use the same function twice. The first when the parameter is `df`, the second when the parameter is `df3`. How to do that? The function:

```
def add(df, df3):
    df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
    df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "timestamp", freq = "h")).agg("mean")
    price = df["price"]
    amount = df["amount"]
    return (price * amount) // amount
```

The double use :

```
out = []

# This loop will use the add(df) function for every csv and append in a list
for f in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    # Replace empty values with numpy, not sure if usefull,  maybe pandas can handle this
    df.replace("", np.nan)  
    #added aggregate DataFrame with new column to list of DataFrames
    out.append(add(df))

out2 = []
df3 = pd.Series(dtype=np.float64)
for f in csv_files:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    df3 = pd.concat([df3, df2], ignore_index=True)

out2 = pd.DataFrame(add(df = df3))
out2
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df3'
```

Comment: You're calling your function `add(df)` while you define it as requiring two parameters.

Comment: I edited my post with the error i get when i write df = df3 in the second loop.
My code is written like that : 
- the function
- The loop to create the first dataframe then use the function on it
- The second loop to creat the second dataframe then use the function on it

Comment: Well, you don't really need `def add(df, df3):`. Just define the function as `def add(df):`. Then, when you want to use it for df3, just pass df3 as the parameter, i.e., `add(df3)`

Comment: Ok then, the results i got is not what i want but the function works fine, thanks for your help and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the `add` function have nothing to do with the variable names `df` and `df3` in the rest of the script.

As @garagnoth has stated, you only need one parameter in `add`. You can call it `df`, `foo` or `myvariablename`: it is not related to nor `df`, nor `df3`.

In your case, you can change the `add` function to the following:

```py
def add(a_dataframe):
    # I set the argument name to "a_dataframe" so you can
    # see its name is not linked to outside variables
    a_dataframe["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(a_dataframe["timestamp"])
    a_dataframe = a_dataframe.groupby(pd.Grouper(key = "timestamp", freq = "h")).agg("mean")
    price = a_dataframe["price"]
    amount = a_dataframe["amount"]
    return (price * amount) // amount
```

You can now call this function with `df` or `df3` as the rest of the script already does.

Comment: It's clear now to me, i didn't enough understand how to use a parameter, thanks